# How to link delegate and sourcedata to only one tableview in a set of tableviews created in the mainstoryboard

Tags: objective-c, delegates, datasource

Please bear with me as I am completely new at objective-c. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

So here is basically what I am trying to accomplish: I have 3 main tables whose contents will never change, that I therefore chose to construct in the mainstoryboard. Think of these are different grouping drilled down step by step into more and more details. So you have:

Table 1 (higher level to table 2) > Table 2 (higher level to table 3) > Table 3

Now I need to add a 4th table, but whose contents will be changed,  based on a CSV file. For now I am ignoring how use CSV files and there seems to be quite a bit of info on this already. So I am electing to use Arrays using (NSArray) to store and retrive the information.

I first build the prototype of this table in the mainstoryboard so that I have an idea of what it will look like. Then I wrote the code below which ideally will update the information in table 4:

```
VIEWCONTROLLER.H file
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UITableViewController
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end

VIEWCONTROLLER.M file

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


NSArray *nominalManagers;
NSArray *tipsManagers;
NSArray *tipsAmt;
NSArray *nominalAmt;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;


    tipsManagers = [[NSArray alloc]
                    initWithObjects:
                    @"SSG",
                    nil];

    tipsAmt = [[NSArray alloc]
                    initWithObjects:
                    @"$tip",
                    nil];

    nominalManagers = [[NSArray alloc]
                    initWithObjects:
                    @"Wel",
                    @"Gold",
                    @"Colch",
                    @"Stand",
                    nil];

    nominalAmt = [[NSArray alloc]
                    initWithObjects:
                    @"$Wel",
                    @"$Gold",
                    @"$Colch",
                    @"$Stand",
                    nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSUInteger rowNum;
    if (section == 0) {
    rowNum = 1;
    }
    else if (section == 1) {
    rowNum = 4;
    }
    else {
    rowNum = 0;
    }

    return rowNum;

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSInteger section = [indexPath section];

    switch (section) {
        case 0: // First cell in section 1
            cell.textLabel.text = [tipsManagers objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tipsAmt objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            break;
        case 1: // Second cell in section 1
            cell.textLabel.text = [nominalManagers objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [nominalAmt objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            break;
        default:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"WRONG SECTION";
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

@end
```

My main issue is that I am unable to connect the delegate and sourcedata of this class to Table 4 (the table whose information will change). Can you help? Do you have any suggestions to better accomplish my goal?

Comment: Can you explain little bit more what is exact problem here, code seems alright except that you do not have a UITableView to connect your data source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from your question is you do not have a uitableview to connect your data source and delegate !?

I am not sure if you have added 4th viewcontroller to your storyboard yet, If not  just add a UItableviewcontroller to your storyboard, create a push segue then in identity inspector choose your VIEWCONTROLLER as class name.

Add  `IBOutlet UITableView`to your .h file like below and in your interface builder connect your datasource and delegate. When you need refresh your tableview call [self.tableviewname reloadData];

You can use NSMutableArray to edit the items in your array, if you use NSArray array items will be static.

VIEWCONTROLLER.H file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UITableViewController
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *fourthTable;

@end
```

VIEWCONTROLLER.M file

```
    @implementation ViewController
    @synthesize fourthTable;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;


    tipsManagers = [[NSArray alloc]
                    initWithObjects:
                    @"SSG",
                    nil];

    tipsAmt = [[NSArray alloc]
                    initWithObjects:
                    @"$tip",
                    nil];

    nominalManagers = [[NSArray alloc]
                    initWithObjects:
                    @"Wel",
                    @"Gold",
                    @"Colch",
                    @"Stand",
                    nil];

    nominalAmt = [[NSArray alloc]
                    initWithObjects:
                    @"$Wel",
                    @"$Gold",
                    @"$Colch",
                    @"$Stand",
                    nil];

 [self.fourthTable reloadData];

}
```

Comment: OK thanks alot for your help! So I updated the code as you suggested, added a UItableview to the mainstoryboard and created a segue from Table 3 to the new Table4.

Comment: @JoelNiamien so have you connected data source and delegate? it should work if you did it

Comment: OK thanks alot for your help! So I updated the code as you suggested, However, when I ran the application I received the following message at the following location: UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; <Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT>. When I hit continue in the debugging window, it takes me at 0x4a6d6c5:  ud2 with the message <Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code = EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0). Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry just saw your previous post. I tried to connect the delegate and datasource as follows: Hold control and select the viewcontroller yellow button on Table 4. Then drag in the empty space of table 4. When i did this, the only outlets i had available were "view" and "fourthtable". I selected both by doing what I just described twice. Then I ran the app and ran into the issue above.

Comment: do you use IOS5 or IOS6 ? if you use IOS 5 change this `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];` to this `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

Comment: OK that worked (I have no clue why and couldnt have figured out on my own) in the sense that I have all the array information showing up including the details. However, they are not broken down in separate sections. Is there something I am missing? I will research this on my own. I dont think it will be too difficult. You have pretty much resolved my main issue. So dont worry if you are tired helping at this point :). Thanks again!!

Comment: ok I think I got it. Thanks again for your help. I have a follow up to this? Is there a a better way to reference this question/answer in my next question so that I dont have retype everything?